# Writing dask dataframe as parquet to s3 throws access denied to Create Bucket, not sure why it tries to create the bucket

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, dask, parquet

I am writing the dask dataframe to s3 , my AWS Batch job tries to create bucket instead of writing data to the path.

The same AWS Batch Job works in Dev environment and in test it fails

df.to_parquet("s3_path")

I initially had overwrite option to the folder , tried removing that overwrite = True , that didnt work too.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].